# Drag and drop in Sliders using Webdriver java

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

In website "http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-drop-range-sliders-demo.html" a slider is present.By default the first slider value is at 10. I was trying to automate the functionality of moving the slider to value of 20. But not able to perform the same. i have used the below code

```
WebElement sliderOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='range']/output"));
        System.out.println(sliderOne.getAttribute("value"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.clickAndHold(sliderOne);
        action.moveByOffset(20, 0).release().build().perform();
```

Please find below HTML code for the slider and image of slider. Kindly help in automating the slider.

```html
<div class="range">
            <input type="range" name="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" onchange="range.value=value">
            <output id="range">10</output>
          </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slider is in the `<input>` tag, not the `<output>` tag. The `<output>` tag is just the value.

```
WebElement sliderOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='range']/input"));
```

Comment: While giving input tag and using the code 'action.moveByOffset(20, 0).release().build().perform();' the slider moves to 61. How can we set the offset in such a way that the slider moves to 20?

Comment: @Dinu the `clickAndHold` is performed in the middle of the element. To move to 20 you need to give negative offset (around -100 I believe). You can devise general formula using `sliderOne.getSize().width` property.

Comment: i was able to move to 20 by using the below code but can u please explain or give some idea how the offset value is calculated.

Comment: 'Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(sliderOne, 40, 0).click();
  action.build().perform();'

Comment: @Dinu The [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-int-int-) has the answer: `"Moves the mouse to an offset from the top-left corner of the element"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to move slider to value 20 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Selenium/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-drop-range-sliders-demo.html");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement sl = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='slider1']/div/input"));
    //Using Action Class
    Actions move = new Actions(driver);
    Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(sl, -79, 0).build();
    action.perform();

}
```

I have tested it and it's working.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to set the exact slider value.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//path to driver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-drop-range-sliders-demo.html");

WebElement eleSlider1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='range']"));
int valueToBeset=40;
valueToBeset=(valueToBeset>1&&valueToBeset<30)?valueToBeset+1:valueToBeset;
int eleSlider1Width=eleSlider1.getSize().getWidth();
int pixelValue=(eleSlider1Width)*valueToBeset/100;       
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(eleSlider1,pixelValue, 0).click().build().perform();
```